# Solving a PDE by method of characteristics

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I solved the following:
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{y}&=\frac{dy'}{2y'+wy}\\
\ln y + \ln C &= \frac{1}{2} \ln \left(2y'+wy\right)\\
2\ln y + \ln C &= \ln \left(2y'+wy\right)\\
C &= \frac{2y'}{y^2} + \frac{w}{y}\\
\end{align}

I isolated the constant since the purpose of solving is to find the differential invariant. However the answer given is:
$$
\frac{y'}{y^2}+\frac{w}{y}
$$

where am I going awry?

Comment: The DE is not separable so you can't integrate it the way you did it.

Comment: yes, I suspected I had oversimplified the situation in my haste.

Comment: Yes It happens sometimes. But the DE is not that complicated to integrate Sarah

Comment: you're right, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is, $y \ \& \ y'$ aren't independent variables, so you can't suppose them as constant when you integrate with respect to the other ones! You must follow **Exact Differential Equations** method instead. By inspiration from given answer, Write it as follows, to see its exactness:
$$\frac{dy}{y} = \frac{dy'}{2y'+\omega y} \Longrightarrow (2y'+\omega y)dy = ydy' \Longrightarrow ydy' - (2y'+\omega y)dy = 0 \Longrightarrow$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{y^2}dy' + (\frac{-2y'}{y^3}+\frac{-\omega}{y^2})dy = 0 \Longrightarrow d(\frac{y'}{y^2}+\frac{\omega}{y}) = 0 \Longrightarrow \frac{y'}{y^2}+\frac{\omega}{y} = C$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dy'}{2y'+wy}$$
$$(2y'+wy){dy}-y{dy'}=0$$
$$wy{dy}+2y'dy-y{dy'}=0$$
Multiply by $y$
$$wy^2{dy}+y'dy^2-y^2{dy'}=0$$
Divide by $y^4$:
$$\dfrac w {y^2}{dy}+\dfrac {y'dy^2-y^2{dy'}}{y^4}=0$$
$$\dfrac w {y^2}{dy}-d\dfrac {y'}{y^2}=0$$
Integrate:
$$-\dfrac w y- \dfrac {y'}{y^2}=k$$
$$\dfrac w y+ \dfrac {y'}{y^2}=C$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the rule $\frac ab=\frac cd\implies \frac ab=\frac cd=\frac{a+c}{b+d}$, add the $ω$ extended first term to the second to find
$$
\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dy'}{2y'+ωy}=\frac{dy'+ωdy}{2y'+2ωy}
$$
Now taking the first and last term this can be directly integrated to
$$
\ln|y|=\frac12\ln|y'+ωy|+c\implies Cy^2=y'+ωy
$$